# Cannot open port 8140 with CentOS 6 Puppet Master

Tags: linux, tcp

I am trying to open port 8140 on my CentOS Puppet Master. I have tried and exhausted every idea/instruction on the internet, still the port seems closed. Here is the iptable, please let me know if there is something wrong.

```
[vagrant@puppetmaster ~]$ sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Aug  4 17:38:36 2016
*filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:680]
    -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8140 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Aug  4 17:38:36 2016
[vagrant@puppetmaster ~]$
```

I have used nmap, checked services and grep 8140, and also nestat as seen below. None of them returns any output which shows to me the port has refused to open.

```
[vagrant@puppetmaster ~]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 8140
[vagrant@puppetmaster ~]$
```

Don't know what to do now. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question, putting some of it in code formatting. To use code formatting, indent something by 4 spaces. Also, I think this is off-topic for Stack Overflow - it probably belongs on our sister sites [SU] or [Unix.SE]. You can flag your question for moderator attention, and ask to have it migrated there. Good luck, hope you'll get useful answers!